# How to receive email alert if anyone answer my question?

Tags: support, email

How to receive email alert if anyone answer my question here, I mean askubuntu.com.

Every time my question was been answer, I only can see the answer when I came here.

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93538/188988) too

Answer (score 7):

Click on the Stack Exchange button on the top left of the site, and then email settings:

[image]

[image]